# Abraham\TwitterOAuth doesn't work on appengine PHP

Tags: php, google-app-engine, twitter, oauth

The following code on PHP appengine works perfectly locally, but when I deploy to http://x.appengine.com there is an issue

Code:

```
<?php 

    require "vendor/autoload.php";
    use Abraham\TwitterOAuth\TwitterOAuth;

    $CONSUMER_KEY = "[redacted]";
    $CONSUMER_SECRET = "[redacted]";
    $OAUTH_CALLBACK = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[HTTP_PORT]";
    $connection = new TwitterOAuth($CONSUMER_KEY, $CONSUMER_SECRET);        
    $request_token = $connection->oauth('oauth/request_token', array('oauth_callback' => $OAUTH_CALLBACK));

    var_dump($request_token);
?>
```

Output:

```
array(1) { ["‹"]=> string(0) "" } array(1) { ["‹"]=> string(0) "" }
```

Any suggestions here? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the issue was with the  CURLOPT_ENCODING => 'gzip', option - commenting out this line in TwitterOAuth.php solved the issue.

Comment: Dam bloody encoding :)